# C++ the dynamic array and file reading don't work together

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, file-io, compiler-construction

Such a code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *test = new int[];
    ifstream f("ofile.txt");
    for (int i=0,v; i<10; i++)
    {
        f>>v;
        test[i]=1; 
        cout<<"\nv = "<<v<<", i = "<<i<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

caused of this message after compiling:

[image]

I guess (correct me if I'm wrong) here is some error about memory, but details are unknown for me. If I remove one of them (file reading or array) it works.
So it will be great to hear an explanation of the problem.

Comment: You didn't specify a size for you allocation!

Comment: i assume you also meant `test[i]=v;` not `test[i]=1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking java.  To allocate an array like that you need to give a size.
e.g.

```
    int *test = new int[20];
```

However a better scheme would be to use a vector of integers.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>  // for sort()

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        std::vector<int> data;
        std::ifstream fsin("ofile.txt");

        int count = 0;
        while (fsin.good())
        {
            int v;
            fsin >> v;
            if (fsin.good())
            {
                data.push_back(v);
                std::cout << "\nv = " << v << ", i = " << count++ << std::endl;
            }
        }

        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());

        for (size_t i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
            std::cout << i << '\t' << data[i] << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The goal is to save the file (it contains numbers only in every string) content in array which may be **re-sorted** later. I guess your example will be convinient after a little changing. But I still can't assemble all this together. Plsss, point out how to do that.

Comment: @srgg6701 - hich part is unclear?  Each time around the loop you read a value from the file into 'v', then append that value to the vector 'test'.  You can then do whatever is required with the vector data.

Comment: Anybody, tell me - why there the condition *if (fsin.good())* is repeated inside the loop *while* (it is already set)? Is it a mistake or it is really necessary?! I'm confused :(

Comment: The inner test confirms that "fin >> v" succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

You have to allocate a fixed size array, `int *test = new int[];` shouldn't even work.

If the size is known, use `int *test = new int[size];`, otherwise try using a `std::vector` or `std:array`.